# TextToSpeech crash when using Accessibility Stream

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

Hello I'm trying to make TextToSpeech work through Accessibility Stream added in API 26.
I've tried to use the bundle parameters as stated in docs but the code crashes the TTS Engine.

Here's the code:

```
Bundle mParamsBundle = new Bundle();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        mParamsBundle.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY));
}

mTextToSpeech.speak(sentence,
                modeAddToQueue ? TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD : TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                mParamsBundle, null);
```

TTS always crash an this log shows:

```
I/TextToSpeech: Asked to disconnect from ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}

I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}

I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
```

What am i doing wrong here? Help would be appreciated

Full Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import java.util.Locale;

public class TextToSpeechHelper implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    final private static float SPEECH_RATE = 0.9f;
    private TextToSpeech mTextToSpeech;
    private Bundle mParamsBundle;
    private Locale mLocale;

    public TextToSpeechHelper(Context context, Locale locale) {
        mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
        mLocale = locale;
        mParamsBundle = new Bundle();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            mParamsBundle.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                    String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY));
        }
    }

    public void speak(String sentence) {
        speak(sentence, true);
    }

    public void speak(String sentence, boolean modeAddToQueue) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mTextToSpeech.speak(sentence,
                    modeAddToQueue ? TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD : TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                    mParamsBundle, null);
        } else {
            mTextToSpeech.speak(sentence,
                    modeAddToQueue ? TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD : TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
        }
    }

    public boolean isSpeaking() {
        return mTextToSpeech.isSpeaking();
    }

    public void release() {
        mTextToSpeech.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(mLocale);
            //mTextToSpeech.setSpeechRate(SPEECH_RATE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/PlayerBase.java#614, `STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY` seems not to be supposed to be used, aside from the use of volume control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AccessibilityService` then do following steps

Step 1 : add [`flagEnableAccessibilityVolume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo#FLAG_ENABLE_ACCESSIBILITY_VOLUME) in [AccessibilityServiceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo)

Note 1 : This flag requests that all audio tracks system-wide with `AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_ACCESSIBILITY` be controlled by the `AudioManager.STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY` volume.

Step 2 : set `AudioAttributes` to `TextToSpeech` object

```
mTextToSpeech.setAudioAttributes( new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_ACCESSIBILITY)
                        .build());
```

[`AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_ACCESSIBILITY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes#USAGE_ASSISTANCE_ACCESSIBILITY) - Usage value to use when the usage is for accessibility, such as with a screen reader.

Note 2 : You don't have to use TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM